# Properly create shared pointer for other objects

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I am trying to use a shared pointer that will be shared to different objects throughout my program. I have noticed that when I create the pointer before giving it to the objects that need it, there is no data. It is probably something to do with how I am implementing the pointers. I have added a sample of what I am trying to do, and what is happening

```
int main() {
    // This would be the data I want to share. For simplicity
    // using a vector of ints
    std::vector<int> data;
    // Create the shared pointer
    // The objects that are getting access are not allowed to change the 
    // the data so thats why I put in const (could be wrong on what that is
    // actually doing)
    std::shared_ptr<const std::vector<int>> pointer_to_vector =
    std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(data);
    // Add data to the object wanting to share
    data.push_back(1);
    data.push_back(2);
    data.push_back(3);
    data.push_back(4);
    // If I look at pointer_to_vector in debu at this point it shows no
    // data, size 0
}
```

If I create the shared pointer (pointer_to_vector) after I add the data (push_back) it works. However if I want to add data to the vector later in the program, the pointer will not be updated, so the objects dont have access to the new data. 
Is there something I am doing wrong, or fundamentally my understanding is wrong?

Comment: "make_shared" means "make a shared object", not "make an object shared". Same difference as between "make me a pizza" and "make me a millionaire".

Comment: How would I make an object shared? Would I have to use the conventional way of pointers with a "*", or can it be done with shared_ptr?

Comment: If the object was dynamically allocated, you can pass a pointer to it to a `shared_ptr` to let the `shared_ptr` assume ownership of it. If it's an automatic or static object, you can't transfer ownership of it.

Answer (score 2):

`data` is unrelated to the instance created with `std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(data);`.

What you really want is

```
std::shared_ptr<const std::vector<int>> pointer_to_vector =
std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(data);
// Add data to the object wanting to share
pointer_to_vector->push_back(1);
pointer_to_vector->push_back(2);
pointer_to_vector->push_back(3);
pointer_to_vector->push_back(4);
```

The vector created with the `std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(data)` takes a copy for initialization. The instances are still unrelated though.

Comment: Sorry had a typo in the the code, "all_ints" was supposed to be "data", fixed it

Comment: @user6768079 I fixed my answer accordingly, and put a bit more of explanation what happens.

Comment: When I used the pointer_to_vector-> I get a "no instance of overload" error

Comment: @user6768079 You cannot create a shared pointer for an object on the stack.

Comment: So if I wanted to share "data" with other objects I would have to use "std::vector<int>* data_pointer" type pointers ?

Comment: @user6768079 You should use a `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>>` for sharing in 1st place. See here which [constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) are available.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
std::vector<int> data;
auto pointer_to_vector = std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(data);
```

creates a new object that is **a copy of `data`** and returns a shared pointer to it.  You then add elements to `data`, but not to the new vector.

However, if you write:

```
auto pointer_to_vector = std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>();
auto& data = *pointer_to_vector;
```

then you have a newly-created vector, and `data` is a **reference** to that object.  The latter looks closer to what you intended.

Comment: I used `auto` when transcribing the example, for legibility, without changing the meaning of any of the code.